# Hadoop: How can I prevent failed tasks from making the whole job fail?

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, cluster-computing

I'm running a hadoop job with, say, 1000 tasks. I need the job to attempt to run every task but many of the tasks will not complete and will instead throw an exception. I cannot change this behavior, but I still need the data obtained from the tasks that did not fail.

How can I make sure Hadoop goes through with all the 1000 tasks despite encountering a large number of failed tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you could set the maximum percentage of tasks that are allowed to fail without triggering job failure. Map tasks and reduce tasks are controlled independently, using the

```
mapred.max.map.failures.percent 
mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent
```

properties. So if you want 70% of tasks result even if 30% fails you could do so with above properties.